# If $f, f^2, \nabla f^2 \in L^2$, what can you say about $\nabla f$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded. If $f, f^2, \nabla f^2 \in L^2(U)$, Is $\nabla f$ in $L^2(U)$.

I see that

$$\|\nabla f^2 \|^2_{L^2(U)} = 2\|f \cdot \nabla f \|^2_{L^2(U)} \leq \|f^2 \|^2_{L^2(U)} + \|[\nabla f]^2 \|^2_{L^2(U)}$$

by Young's inequality which does not take me anywhere. Any hint?

Comment: Consider the case $0\in U$ and $f=r^\alpha$.

Comment: Be careful distinguishing between $|\nabla f|^2$ and $\nabla (f^2)$